# iphone:cant identify longpress event in webView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview

I m working on eBook app.I open my book pages in webView.No In my index page i have put the functionality to sent email and print the content of book as below:

[image]

Now my problem is that when i click on link it goes to the webview delegate method.And on the long press click i open the ActionSheet.Now when i long press it open the actionsheet but it doesn't go to webview delegate method.I mean webView cant detect the longpress event so that i cant get the URL of link.
Thanks in advance.please suggest me the way to do this.
Here is my code for generating long press:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
longPress.minimumPressDuration=0.2;
longPress.delegate = self;
[webView addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

[longPress release];
```

control directly goes to this method when long press event fire.

```
- (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture {
       [gesture.view becomeFirstResponder];
       UIActionSheet *action=[[[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"testing" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Email",@"Print", nil]autorelease];
       [action showInView:self.view]; 
}
```

And the doesn't go to webview delegate method

```
      - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
```

Comment: post your `UIActionSheetDelegate` implementation method